# How to make MS Excel cells display dark background with white text instead of the reverse which is default?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2016

By default, MS Excel cells displays white background with black text. This is glaring to the eyes. Some even find it painful. How can we make MS Excel to display  black/dark background with white text instead?

I'm sure many of us will find this more comfortable to our eyes.

I am using MS Excel 2016 on Windows 10.

Comment: You could change the Normal Style to have a Fill that is black and Font that is white. Unfortunately, you won't be able to see the gridlines if you do that. You can give the rest of the interface a dark theme using Options | General | Personalize your copy of Microsoft Office | Office Theme | Black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*The most easiest method I can suggest you is VBA (Macro).*

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim xsheet As Worksheet 

For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select
    With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 5000))
        .Interior.Color = vbCyan
        .Font.Name = "Calibri"
        .Font.Size = "11"
        .Font.Color = vbWhite
    End With
    Next xsheet
End Sub
```

**How it works:**

1. Press `Alt+F11` to open VB editor.
2. Find & Click the `This Workbook` Icon.
3. Select `Workbook` from left Dropdown & `Open` 
   from right Dropdown.
4. Copy & Paste lines from `ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select` to `End With` & Save 
   the Workbook.

*Next time when you open the Workbook, you find the new look.*

**Note,** *Sheet's dimension, Interior & Font Color as well as Font name & size  are editable.*

Comment: Is it possible to do this through certain settings/configuration?

Comment: @curious, few parameters are possible, but this method is handy. One more possibility is create TEMPLATE & use it .

Comment: I tested your VBA code. Only the first worksheet is affected. The other worksheets are not. This is a problem for excel files with multiple worksheets. One more thing. `.Interior.Color = vbCyan` needs to be changed to vbBlack for black background.

Comment: write `vbBlack` instead & for me it's working for other also,, but  wait I'll return soo.

Comment: @curious, add these lines before **ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Select** `Dim xsheet As Worksheet
For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` and `Next xsheet` after **End With**

Comment: Sure @TomBrunberg,, soon I'll.

Comment: As I mentioned in my comment on the question, setting a fill colour for all cells will hide the gridlines.

Comment: Glad to help you @curious ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 4):

This updated code makes all sheets black and adds cell borders to simulate the grid lines;

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim xsheet As Worksheet

    For Each xsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        xsheet.Select
        With Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1048576, 5000))
            .Interior.Color = vbBlack 'xlNone '
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            '.Font.Size = "11"
            .Font.Color = vbWhite 'vbBlack
            .Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .Borders.Weight = xlThin
            .Borders.ColorIndex = 49 'colors here http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/excel/colors.htm
        End With
    
    Next xsheet

End Sub
```